# Xcode 6 - Make Asset Catalog automatically recognize PDFs

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf, vector, asset-catalog

I have been having a minor but very annoying issue ever since Xcode 6 launched with support for PDFs in asset catalogs.

When I drag a PDF into the asset catalog, Xcode recognizes it as a "Bitmap" image. So, I have to go to the "Attributes Inspector" and change the image type to "Vector". Even worse, I then have to drag the image from "Unassigned" to the correct slot.

As you can imagine, when importing dozens of images this is very painful.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you!